# Can you partially answer a question with a work-in-progress?

Tags: discussion

Suppose there's a long, difficult post that has many steps and parts to it. Would you be allowed to post a "partial" answer, including everything that you've solved so far, and edit it as you progress? Or do you have to provide the entire answer to the puzzle in the first revision?

Comment: @bobble Sort of, but it doesn't really seem to actually give a yes or no answer, or really go in-depth on what a Partial Answer actually is on Puzzling Stack Exchange.

Comment: There are three tests given for partial answers and two examples - what more do you want?

Comment: The duplicate-target answers this question pretty clearly right in its question - 'Puzzling [...] allow[s] "partial answers" -- that is, answers that aren't full answers to the questions, but just make some progress towards answering it.'  So, "yes", you're allowed. The answers to that question go pretty in-depth into what would be needed to count as a Partial Answer on this site.